# How to add a simple "colorbar" to a network-graph plot in python?

Tags: python, networkx, colorbar

I was wondering how can I simply add a colorbar to my plot. I have to following code, which plots a graph by reading a gml file. I have a set of numbers to assign to the edges as their colors and I just want to see a colorbar right next to the plot so I can analyze the colors. When I add the `plt.colorbar(g)` it gives me error. How can I add a colorbar without going through all the process of actually building the colorbar?

```
H = nx.read_gml('./network1.gml')

EAM = EigenVectorCentrality( EAMatrix );

x = [];
for eam in EAM[0]:
    x.append(eam[0]);

 degs =  H.degree().values();
 plt.clf()
 g = nx.draw(H, with_labels=0, edge_color=x, node_size=70, font_size=9, width=1)
 plt.axis('equal')     
 plt.colorbar(g);
 plt.show()
```

And here is the Nerwork1.gml file:

```
graph
[
   node
   [
    id 1
   ]
 node
[
    id 2
]
node
[
    id 3
]
node
[
    id 4
]
    node
[
    id 5
]
    node
[
    id 6
]
    node
[
    id 7
]
    node
[
    id 8
]
    node
[
    id 9
]
    node
[
    id 10
]
    node
[
    id 11
]
edge
[
    source 1
    target 2
]
edge
[
    source 1
    target 2
]
edge
[
    source 1
    target 3
]
edge
[
    source 1
    target 4
]
edge
[
    source 1
    target 5
]
edge
[
    source 2
    target 3
]
edge
[
    source 2
    target 4
]
edge
[
    source 2
    target 5
]
edge
[
    source 3
    target 4
]
edge
[
    source 3
    target 5
]
edge
[
    source 4
    target 5
]
edge
[
    source 6
    target 7
]
edge
[
    source 6
    target 8
]
edge
[
    source 6
    target 9
]
edge
[
    source 6
    target 10
]
edge
[
    source 7
    target 8
]
edge
[
    source 7
    target 9
]

edge
[
    source 7
    target 10
]
edge
[
    source 8
    target 9
]
edge
[
    source 8
    target 10
]
edge
[
    source 9
    target 10
]
edge
[
    source 5
    target 6
]
edge
[
    source 5
    target 11
]
 edge
 [
    source 6
    target 11
 ]
]
```

Comment: `nx.draw` returns `None`, that is why `plt.colorbar` fails. Also: could you post the file `network1.gml` somewhere?

Comment: I added the network.gml to the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since I did not have your data available, I used [this simple example](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/examples/drawing/edge_colormap.html) from the networx homepage. But it should be trivial for you to use it in your code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G=nx.star_graph(20)
pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
colors=range(20)
cmap=plt.cm.Blues
vmin = min(colors)
vmax = max(colors)
nx.draw(G, pos, node_color='#A0CBE2', edge_color=colors, width=4, edge_cmap=cmap,
           with_labels=False, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(vmin = vmin, vmax=vmax))
sm._A = []
plt.colorbar(sm)
plt.show()
```

This does the trick, but I agree, it is a bit sad that `nx.draw` just returns `None`.

Comment: Thanks, it is working, but it is sad that there is not an easy way to do that and all is because of `nx.draw` which returns `None` as you said.

Comment: It solved my problem but technically it didn't suggest any _simple_ way. Anyways thanks and I used your answer. Thanks

Comment: The suggested link is now broken.

Comment: Thanks! Here's the new location: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/examples/drawing/edge_colormap.html

Comment: I keep getting this error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'normalize'` referring to `norm=plt.normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)`. I couldn't find it anywhere...

Comment: I solved my problem. All I had to do was to call `mynodes=nx.draw_networkx_nodes()` and then call `plt.colorbar(nodes,cmap=whatever)` to make it work!

Comment: works great, though I had to capitalize the "n" in "normalize".

Comment: For those wondering why the comments don't make much sense anymore: The post has been edited. There's a capital in "Normalize" now.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but for people looking for that now, you can also use `nx.draw_networkx_nodes` and `nx.draw_networkx_edges` separately, since both these functions return a pathcollection with can be given to `plt.colorbar`. For example

```py
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
pathcollection = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color=nx.get_node_attribute(G, "color"))
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)
plt.colorbar(pathcollection)
```