# How do I add a colorbar of sorts to a networkx graph where node colors are based upon a centrality measure?

Tags: networkx, colorbar

I'm trying to color nodes in a network based upon betweenness centrality values:

```
G = nx.karate_club_graph()
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
BC=nx.betweenness_centrality(G,normalized=False,weight='weight')
values = [BC.get(node, 0.25) for node in G.nodes()]
nx.draw(G, cmap=plt.get_cmap('viridis'), node_color=values, with_labels=True, 
font_color='white')
plt.show()
```

Nodes are colored. However, the coloring does not convey which nodes have the highest betweenness values. Is there a means to add a colorbar of sorts?

Comment: Hey - have a look at this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739248/how-to-add-a-simple-colorbar-to-a-network-graph-plot-in-python

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful.